# Does web3.eth.wallet.create set the newly created wallet file as the 'global' source of addresses for the web3 instance?

Tags: web3js-v1.x

I'm playing about with web3js@1.0.0-beta.55 and I'm setting an HttpProvider on Ganache for my web3 instance:

```
this.web3Instance = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(environment.ethereum.provider));
```

I've noticed that if I call `this.web3Instance.eth.getAccounts()`  it returns the Ganache accounts, as I would've expected. 
 However, if I create a new wallet using `this.web3Instance.eth.accounts.wallet.create(1);`
 and then call `getAccounts()` again, it returns the address from the newly created wallet file, and not the accounts on my Ethereum node (i.e. Ganache).

I fail to understand why - any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - I could've sworn I checked the documentation on this, of which there is a very clear explanation. My mistake.

From the [web3js docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts) for:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts([callback]):
```

> Will return a list of the unlocked accounts in the Web3 wallet or it
>   will return the accounts from the currently connected node.
>
> This means you can add accounts with web3.eth.accounts.create() and
>   you will get them returned here.

Although it specifies this behaviour for `web3.eth.accounts.create()` the same applies for `web3.eth.accounts.load()` and possibly other functions.